# Adding columns from a table to a different table with extra columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. Create a new table. The new table will contain a class number and the name of the class manager (other names, not existing data)
2. Write a query that will show each employee his first name, surname, and the name of his manager

I already have the first table that has all the details of the employees, and now I would like to add it to a different table with specific columns (employees first name (from first table), surname (from first table), (name of the manager (the second table))

Thank you !

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Thank you! but i have tried alone and i think i need some assistant

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

you can do a simple join:

```
Select e1.FirstName, e1.LastName, e2.ManagerName
from first_table e1
inner join second_table e2
on e1.classKey = e2.classKey
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @JustAskingSmartPeople remember to mark the answer as "accepted" if it helped you - click the tick next to the answer so it turns green.